# The logical way of class interconnections in a system

Tags: class, oop

I am new to coding and I  was wondering what is the logical way of representing the interconnections between classes of a system, more specifically the GUI class and the system's classes. Let's consider an online ordering system. In addition, let's consider that we need to make an order in this system. So I imagine that there is a GUI ( after logging in ) and there is a button for make order. So this means that the GUI class will be connected directly to the make order class  ( if we assume that there is a class that is responsible for making orders )? Or there should be some intermediate class that should be connected to the GUI and controls the logic of the system ( if user choices make order then this control class deals with the make order class, if user choices to track order then this class deals with the track order class and so on )?  I am looking for the most efficient way of writing code.

Edit:  In many textbooks, they mention three types of classes that deal with this issue which are boundary class ( GUI), controller class and Logical class, but actually I don't know the exact meaning of the controller and the logical classes types.

Answer (score 1):

MVC is one famous pattern used for this specific purpose. MVC stands for model view controller.

View = Classes responsible for the UI.
Model = This is the business domain where all complex business logic lives. OOP is heavily used here.
Controller = This connects the view with the model. Example - a click on the UI needs to be fulfilled by a model and the controller will connect the UI to that model.

Add REST to this mix which will help UI communicate with Model and the make the model agnostic to type of clients being Web, Mobile or even another server. Angular, React etc are heavily used for UI presentation.

You would needs a persistent layer to persist the state of the model and read it back. Example - A database which can save historical order and read them back. JPA and Hibernate are famous tools for this.

You don't need to deal this raw MVC, rather use one of many web frameworks which will take care of boiler plate code for you. Spring MVC is one such framework in Java world. There are equally famous frameworks for python, node, scala etc. This framework will have standard ways to do REST, Persistence, controller etc. So start from this.